# Hot reload not working if project created on non-system drive

Tags: uno-platform

Simply creating two empty projects from Uno template.

Drive `C:/test` - XAML hot reload working

```
[DEBUG] dbug: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.Host.HotReload.ServerHotReloadProcessor[0]
[DEBUG]       Base project path: C:\test\App1\App1\App1.Droid\App1.Droid.csproj
[DEBUG] dbug: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.Host.HotReload.ServerHotReloadProcessor[0]
[DEBUG]       Xaml Search Paths: C:\test\App1\App1\App1.Shared
[DEBUG] dbug: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.Host.HotReload.ServerHotReloadProcessor[0]
[DEBUG]       File C:\test\App1\App1\App1.Shared\MainPage.xaml changed
```

(the last line sees MainPage.xaml change)

Drive `D:/test` - XAML hot reload **NOT** working

```
[DEBUG] dbug: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.Host.HotReload.ServerHotReloadProcessor[0]
[DEBUG]       Base project path: D:\test\App1\App1\App1.Droid\App1.Droid.csproj
[DEBUG] dbug: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.Host.HotReload.ServerHotReloadProcessor[0]
[DEBUG]       Xaml Search Paths: D:\test\App1\App1\App1.Shared
```

(no log when changing MainPage.xaml and no UI changes)

It took me 3 days to figure it out. Please help to find the root cause.

Comment: That is a very interesting problem, I will try on my machine

Comment: @MartinZikmund have you managed to replicate the problem? Thanx for your involvement

Comment: Hi, not yet, sorry. Hopefully today